# Setting properties in parent view/template in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to set the `title` tag in the application template, from a child view/controller in Phoenix.

The `title` tag is inside the `web/templates/layout/app.html.eex` template, but I have an `ArticlesController` which renders to the `<%= @inner %>` Coming from Rails I'd use the `yield` call, but can't find its equivalent in Phoenix.

What is the right way to pass properties up to the parent template/view from its child?

Comment: This post covers precisely this: http://sevenseacat.net/2015/06/01/custom_page_titles_in_phoenix.html

Comment: Thanks José! This is very helpful!

Comment: 3 options presented here: http://cloudless.studio/articles/27-implementing-page-specific-titles-in-phoenix

Comment: Another variation: https://ryanwinchester.ca/posts/yielding-to-content-in-phoenix-templates

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple of options here. I assume you want something like `content_for` in rails.

One option is to use `render_existing/3` http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/0.14.0/Phoenix.View.html#render_existing/3

Another flexible way is to use a plug:

```
defmodule MyApp.Plug.PageTitle do

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, opts) do
    assign(conn, :page_title, Keyword.get(opts, :title)
  end

end
```

Then in your controller you can do

```
defmodule FooController do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  plug MyApp.Plug.PageTitle, title: "Foo Title"
end

defmodule BarController do
  use MyApp.Web, :controller
  plug MyApp.Plug.PageTitle, title: "Bar Title"
end
```

And in your template;

```
<head>
  <title><%= assigns[:page_title] || "Default Title" %></title>
</head>
```

Here we use `assigns` instead of `@page_title` because `@page_title` will raise if the value is not set.

Comment: Thanks Gazler! I was able to solve this using your recommendation for the template, and adding `page_title: "a title"` to the `render` call in the controller action. 